# The Heaviside functions in the following?

Tags: calculus, analysis, summation

For $(\mu_{i})_{i=\overline{1,n}}$ are real positive parameters, we have $H$ is the Heaviside function, i.e
$$\forall i = \overline{1,n}, ~~~~H(u-\mu_i)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \quad \mbox{if }\ u>\mu_i \\[0.1cm]
                                      0 & \quad \mbox{if }\ u<\mu_i .
\end{array}
\right.$$

**Please I would appreciate the feedback.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\mu_1<\mu_2<\cdots<\mu_n$. Then if $u<\mu_1$, then $S=0$. If $u\in(\mu_i,\mu_{i+1})$, then $S=i$. If $u>\mu_n$, then $S=n$.

Comment: So according to you, we need to make an assumption on the parameters $\mu_i$ for us to calculate $S$?

Comment: Yes, you have to arrange them.

Comment: If we have $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, can I note  this cases as subsets of $\Omega$, we put the case $u(x)>\mu_{n} $ as $\Omega_\mu= \{ x \in \Omega ~:~ u(x)>\mu_{n} \}$ and the case $u<\mu_1$ as the complementary of $\Omega_\mu$ which is $\Omega \setminus \Omega_{i}$ and so on, is it do-able and correct??

Comment: @hanaachan, I think so.